# numpy select question multiple conditions

Tags: numpy

I'm looking for a way to code a numpy select statement that does the same as an SQL case statement.   I have a dataframe name df1 with the following columns:
up1, up2, sc1, sc2, st1, st2

My SQL script would look like:
CASE sc1
when "UP_MJB"  then st1
when "UP_MSCI" then st2
else ""

How do I code it using np.select?   Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume df be the pandas dataframe that has your data

```
conds = [(df['sc1']=='UP_MJB'),(df['sc1']=='UP_MSCI')]
actions = [df['st1'],df['st2']]

df['new_col'] = np.select(conds,actions,default=df['sc1'])
```

`default` parameter is used if none of the case is satisfied. In this example, it'll retain the value of col 'sc1'.

Refer https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html for more info.